# Gatling: Save random attribute in another attribute

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

Is it possible to save an attribute at runtime and then save it as another attribute? For instance, I have an ID that is used in the URL, I've captured it from one page, however there are a list of 5 on the page. I can use findAll to select them all, and then ${AttributeName.random()} to select one at random.

However how do I then go and save that as an attribute and then use it elsewhere? As it needs to be the same each time and if I run random again obviously it'll change string each time.

I could do an ${AttributeName(storedRandomNumber)} but the code could start to be a little messy and was wondering if there was something a little cleaner to use?

Answer (score 0):

You could make another exec() right after this request to assign the random value you want with the `session.set()` method, this value then is saved for the entire thread to be reused.

EX :

```
val scenario = scenario("scenarioName")
.exec(
  http("<-- Name Of Request -->")
    .get("<LINK _TO_FIRST_REQ>")
    .check(jsonPath("$.items[*].id").findAll.optional.saveAs("ListOfAttributeNames"))
)
.exec( session => session.set("randomAttributeNameSelected", session("ListOfAttributeNames").as[Seq[String]]
  .apply(scala.util.Random
    .nextInt((session("ListOfAttributeNames").as[Seq[String]].size - 0) + 1)))
)
.exec(
  http("We use the ID here")
    .get(session => "http://domain.something.com/api/" + session("randomAttributeNameSelected").as[String])
)
```

Thus anytime in the same thread if you access `session("randomAttributeNameSelected").as[String]` it will give you random ID.